# Check for licensing level in ArcGIS 10.2.2

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, arcgis-license-manager

I am in process of migrating some legacy code from 10.0 to 10.2.2. As part of application, I need to make sure user is using ArcEditor (now called Standard) level license. Current logic looks at the registry setting to establish the license level. I wanted to get some feedback from developer community if there is a better way of doing this without using registry setting.

```
        pRegSubKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\ESRI\License10.0")
        pRegLicenseValue = pRegSubKey.GetValue("SOFTWARE_CLASS")

        If Not pRegLicenseValue Is Nothing Then
            Select Case pRegLicenseValue
                Case "Viewer"
                    pArcMapLicense = ArcMapLicenseLevel.ArcView
                Case "Editor"
                    pArcMapLicense = ArcMapLicenseLevel.ArcEditor
                Case "Professional"
                    pArcMapLicense = ArcMapLicenseLevel.ArcInfo
            End Select
        End If
```

Comment: Jay, does this get the currently specified license from desktop adimin?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [Display Product License And Extensions Information Snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Display_Product_License_And_Extensions_Information_Snippet/0049000000pr000000/) function in ArcObject or the [Check Product](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003r000000) function in arcpy.

Comment: That's for extensions. To get the desktop/engine license you would be looking at AOInitialize http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004200000006000000. The trouble is you have to know in advance which product to request and without getting it right you could (and do) get two license levels on the same computer - one for desktop and one for a standalone application.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMiles-Stimson for pointing it you.  I've provided the intended link.  Although I am not aware of the issue you are mentioning.

Comment: This is a problem when you run ArcGis desktop *and* a standalone application on a floating license manager @ericchiasson. Desktop sets its product using Desktop Administrator and the standalone application tries to get the license it was written for, starting with basic up to advanced. In a situation where you are using Standard or Advanced desktop and run a standalone application you are consuming two licenses (assuming one is available) the desktop license and basic for the standalone. If you have limited licenses this causes angst!

Comment: I managed to find a sample on this site and seems like this is what i was looking for, haven't tested it but will update on what i find, link here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000066000000